# What next step could I take to solve the Dec. 4 cryptoquote from the Wisconsin State Journal?

Tags: cipher

So as you might or might not know, I enjoy solving cryptoquotes (also known as cryptograms), and sometimes get stuck on them. Here is today's cryptoquote from the Wisconsin State Journal:

```
EV ORRY UEPR FRDAV, EV

GDATROU URDBG. EV XEVURA

RVNLM. - XEFFEDP WFDHR
```

Now here is my attempt at solving it:

1. First, I noticed that there were only two first names that I could come up with that satisfied the conditions of having a double letter (e.g. `BALLOON` having `LL` and `OO` as double letters), the same letter before and after the double letter, and 3 other unique letters: `JEFFERY` and `WILLIAM`. However, since we are not allowed to substitute a letter with itself, `WILLIAM` is the only valid option. This is what I had for the cryptoquote at that point:

```
I        IM  L A    I   A
EV ORRY UEPR FRDAV, EV GDATROU

  A    I  WI             WILLIAM
URDBG, EV XEVURA RVNLM - XEFFEDP WFDHR
```

2. I then noticed that if `V=N`, then I could make the substitutions `U=T` and `R=E`, meaning that I could get that `A=R`, which helped me get this far:

```
IN SEED TIME LEARN  IN  AR EST
EV ORRY UEPR FRDAV, EV GDATROU

TEA    IN WINTER EN      WILLIAM   A E
URDBG, EV XEVURA RVNLM - XEFFEDP WFDHR
```

However, even though I'm so close, I am genuinely unsure how to progress from here. Here are my substitutions so far:

```
+---+---+---+
|A=R|K= |U=T|
+---+---+---+
|B= |L= |V=N|
+---+---+---+
|C= |M= |W= |
+---+---+---+
|D=A|N= |X=W|
+---+---+---+
|E=I|O=S|Y=D|
+---+---+---+
|F=L|P=M|Z= |
+---+---+---+
|G= |Q= |
+---+---+
|H= |R=E|
+---+---+
|I= |S= |
+---+---+
|J= |T= |
+---+---+
```

Comment: Given that it seems to discuss seasons from a farmer's point of view ("seed time" and "winter", I'd guess at `_AR_EST` (`GDATROU`) being `HARVEST`, which gives `G->H` and `T->V`; I'd also guess that `TEA__` (`URDBG`) is `TEACH`, giving `B->C` and confirming `G->H`, and see if you can work from there.

Comment: _(after that, my next step would probably be to ask google...)_

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "(after that, my next step would probably be to ask google...)" Fair I guess, if I were having trouble with the cryptoquote after that, although I think I might be able to get it from here.

Comment: Note also that you have a probably decrypt for `F` (`->L`), so your last word (`WFDHR`) should currently read as `_LA_E`.

Comment: For what it's worth, working from nil, I'd probably attack it starting with `EV` and looking at likely two-letter words that might start multiple phrases in a quote, with `IN`, and `ON` being the most likely, followed closely by `IF` and `TO` in longer phrases.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Oh yeah, I must have missed that `F` in the last name! Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @JeffZeitlin has pointed out, the agricultural term “seed time” is often paired with “harvest” (as in translations of [Genesis 8:22](https://biblehub.com/genesis/8-22.htm)).  This gives `G→H` and `T→V`.

```
IN SEED TIME LEARN, IN HARVEST
EV ORRY UEPR FRDAV, EV GDATROU

TEA H, IN WINTER EN    - WILLIAM  LA E
URDBG, EV XEVURA RVNLM - XEFFEDP WFDHR
```

The only word that matches `TEA_H` is `TEACH`, so `B→C`.

Next, let's focus on the word `EN___`.  We know that the last three letters *can't* be any of `ACDEHILMNRSTVW`, since those have already been used.

> The only commonly-used word that fits is `ENJOY`.

(A brute-force search of my spell-check dictionary gives the alternative [Enugu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enugu), but this is ruled out since N and M can't map to the same letter.)

Now, it's just a matter of figuring out the author of the quote.  The easy way is to paste the quote into Google, to get:

> [William Blake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Blake), in [“Proverbs of Hell”](https://poets.org/poem/proverbs-hell).